# Onshore / Offshore (Team and Testing)

Tags: testing, team, offshore

Can anyone describe to me what **Onshore / Offshore team** is and what **Onshore / Offshore testing** is? Because i am studying [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2562945) article and I can't find anywhere the specific meanings about the above phrases.

Comment: Does google and wiki not provide enough of an answer?

Comment: I searched about them but especially for the testing, the links where about companies that experts in testing and just refer that they provide those 2 methods (offshore / onshore). For the team, I read in SAP's page in one post that the onshore team is the one that gathers info from customers and the offshore is the one that develop / build the software. So, I am a little confused about what all these mean at last.

Comment: Offshore basically means that the team is situated in a different country, but is still employed by your company. Some confuse it with outsourcing where the team is employed by a different company.  Offshore testing is hence when a testing team is located offshore. Onshore is the opposite - when the team is in your country. This has nothing to do with Programmers.SE though, except it being widely used in IT.

Comment: I had no idea in which Stack Exchange community to write my post, so I found this one and searched the questions. I noticed that there were not similar, but about management so I decided to post it here.
I understood what you said to me about the Onshore/ Offshore so thank you.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @GlenH7 I searched for the terms very well in Google. It just nothing helped me understand because I never heard those terms before and in different links there was different explanations.

Comment: Not to be confused with the terms from e.g. the drilling and mining industry where off-shore = not on land.

Comment: I hadn't saw those terms. I only asked this question for educational reason. The paper i am reading only mention the off-shore and on-shore testing. But if i will see the terms you said I will have in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to start with the terms "in-house" and "outsourced" with respect to development.

- **In-house** means software development performed by employees of the company that is paying for development.
- **Outsourced** means software development performed by employees of a different company that is paying for development.  Outsourced development frequently stills requires an in-house employee to oversee the outsourced development.

With those two concepts, you can extend to the geographic location of the developers.

- **On-shore** development means that the developers are located in the same geography of the company that is paying for the development.
- **Off-shore** development means that the developers are located in a different geography, and more specifically in a different country, than the company that is paying for the development.

Note that you can have in-house development that is also off-shore.  Large multinational development firms (IBM, Microsoft, various consulting agencies, etc...) have branches in multiple countries and can share development tasks across those different teams.

More often than not though, off-shore generally refers to outsourced development.

---

As far as **on-shore** and **off-shore testing**, it's the same model as development.  The on | off shore aspect refers to the geographic location of the testing with regards to the company paying for the project.

It's not uncommon to see hybrid combinations of those teams.  For example, there may be a smaller, core development team that is in-house and on-shore that guides the work of a larger off-shore team that may or may not be out-sourced.  Some of the testing may be handled by the off-shore team, with key tests handled by the in-house, on-shore team as a means of additional QA on the work being done.

Comment: I think there's a subtlety in your definition of "In-house" in that sometimes companies bring contractors in to work on in-house teams as if they were employees.  "Outsourced" means that in some sense responsibility for delivering a product is placed outside the company, as opposed to contracting companies that are merely contracting out developers.